# Eclipse - Edit web.xml like Netbeans (GUI)

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, web.xml

I'm learning Java EE from scratch, and in the tutorial I'm following they're using netbeans to configure web.xml and other content descriptors (like Glassfish descriptor). Because they use it graphic interface from Netbeans, I can't find to do the same on Eclipse. Just the xml file. Is there a way to configure the web.xml from a graphic interface like I do in netbeans?

Comment: You can check Jboss Tools plug-in. I do not know how netbeans GUI, but JBoss Tools plug-in provides a GUI for web.xml. I hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A NetBeans tutorial that does not show you the resulting source from making edits in a GUI is worthless for Eclipse. Eclipse does not yet have editors for web.xml and other Java EE module descriptors. There are third party plugins with such editors, but they aren't going to match NetBeans editors.

You may also want to track the work at Eclipse to develop such editors:

http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/webtools.java-ee-config