# How to create GUI for an xml?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, user-interface, ide

How to create a GUI for my own XML DOM in Eclipse? (like `web.xml, ejb-jar.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<keyword>
<shortCode id="12121">
        <keyword name="MONEY" aliases="AIRTEL MONEY,MNEY,AMONEY,AIRTELMONEY"/>
        <keyword name="DISCOUNTS" aliases="DISCOUNT,OFFER,OFFERS,DEALS"/>
    </shortCode>
            <shortCode id="570600">
        <keyword name="EASY #"  aliases="EASYAD,EASYADD"/>
        <keyword name="ADDISCOVERY"/>
    </shortCode>
</keyword>
```

Comment: Searching is a blessing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661406/which-eclipse-plugin-enables-using-xml-to-define-gui

Comment: I am curious... which product/plugin did this ejb-jar.xml editor come from?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805859/eclipse-edit-web-xml-like-netbeans-gui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure, Eclipse does not "convert" XML-Files to GUIs. There are editors/views implemented for specific types of XML-Files you want to edit. In your case, someone implemented an editor for "Deployment Descriptor XML files" (ejb-jar.xml).

This is what you need to do: Think about how a GUI for your specific XML should look like, and implement an editor. Since editors are part of eclipse-plugins, you will end up implementing an eclipse-plugin for your use-case.

You can find a lot of information about eclipse plug-in development (PDE) on the web.

Comment: As per your answer I understand: It is part of eclipse plug-in development (PDE). Am I right?

Comment: What I wanted to say is, that you will have to program a plugin for eclipse. That plugin contains an Editor ("GUI") that can handle your XML-files (all done by yourself).
So you will have to deal with eclipse plugin development in order to write your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The ejb-jar.xml editor that you referenced was built with a framework called Sapphire.

http://www.eclipse.org/sapphire/